# Facebook SDK 3.0 launch view controller once authorised

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook

Can someone give me a pointer?

I have installed the FacebookSDK 3.0 and have been building a simple Login App.

I have a ViewController called 'LoginViewController' with a Button which you click and it authorises with Facebook to open a NavigationController called 'MenuViewController'

At the moment I have them linked via a Modal Segue,e I believe this is wrong and need some advice on how to link it correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this doc on Facebook [developer](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/).

It explains how to handle login and logout functionalities. And once you login from safari it returns to the app, and your method will be called which is set by notification.

Use that method and show the nextViewController(MenuViewController) in your own app as per the requirement.